# problem while trimming the NSstring in objective c in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, trim

i have a string like "qytwyqteqe"   i want only qytwyqteqe but not the symbol ""

i tried to trim this string using the following code but its giving error  can any one help me pls, thanx in advance

```
   [[strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"""  withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

its giving error for this one @""" 
error:  missing terminating ""
```

edited:

actually i have an array like this

```
arrConvertedDirNames:(
    "(\n    \"(\\n    \\\"Sudha-feb16-2011-02.30PM\\\"\\n)\"",
    "\n    \"Tharanga-jan16-2011-10.30AM\"\n)\n"
)
```

i have done following replacements to remove escaping sequence

```
NSMutableString *strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDownloadedDirNames objectAtIndex:0]];

     [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\""  withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"  withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n    \""  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\"\n"  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

     [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n"  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")"  withString:@""  options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"("  withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")\" "  withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];


     [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\""  withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];


    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" "  withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];

    [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\""  withString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [strTrimmedDownloadedDirNames length])];
now am getting this array
arrConvertedDirNames:(
    "Sudha-feb16-2011-02.30PM",
    "Tharanga-jan16-2011-10.30AM"
)
```

but this array should be like this

```
arrConvertedDirNames:(
    Sudha-feb16-2011-02.30PM ,
    Tharanga-jan16-2011-10.30AM
)
```

what can be done to make array so,, please can any one help me

Comment: "\"" should be used as " is a escape character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `"`, meaning:

this: `replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"""`

should be: `replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\""`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSCharacterSet *charterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"""];
stringWithoutCurrentSymbol = [stringWithAnySimbols stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charterSet];
```

be carefully Returns a new string made by **removing from both ends** of the receiver characters contained in a given character set.